# How to avoid hairpin VPN on cisco

Tags: vpn, nat, cisco-asa

I currently have a hairpin VPN setup with a Cisco ASA, but I'm not very happy as it messes up service access that are on ASA external IP address and are NAT'ed inwards :( How should I re-design the network using extra kit if necessary to avoid the hairpin VPN? I have full control over flow/routing of IPs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place your publicly accessible resources in a DMZ that is publicly addressed, hair-pinning will likely not be required.